# Booting updated system with encrypted root partion fails

Tags: linux, disk-encryption

I've just updated my Debian system to Bullseye and using the 5.10.0-13-amd64 kernel can no longer access my encrypted root disc.

I can still boot using previous version 5.4.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 kernel.

The error reported is "error allocating crypto tfm" and "Dependency failed for local encrypted volumes".

It does not say what the dependency is.  One suspects a crypto module is missing but examining the initrd contents it seems it's all there.

The LUKS header looks like this:

```
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          4
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]

Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           27d09a50-bc61-473e-8c45-12295f45a319
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
        offset: 16777216 [bytes]
        length: (whole device)
        cipher: aes-xts-plain64
        sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
        Key:        512 bits
        Priority:   normal
        Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
        Cipher key: 512 bits
        PBKDF:      argon2i
        Time cost:  4
        Memory:     735048
        Threads:    4
...
```

The crypto modules in the initrd (built using dracut and including cbc.ko which I forced in) are:

```
kernel/arch/x86/crypto
kernel/arch/x86/crypto/aesni-intel.ko
kernel/arch/x86/crypto/crc32c-intel.ko
kernel/arch/x86/crypto/crct10dif-pclmul.ko
kernel/arch/x86/crypto/glue_helper.ko
kernel/arch/x86/crypto/sha256-ssse3.ko
kernel/crypto
kernel/crypto/aes_generic.ko
kernel/crypto/af_alg.ko
kernel/crypto/algif_hash.ko
kernel/crypto/algif_skcipher.ko
kernel/crypto/ansi_cprng.ko
kernel/crypto/async_tx
kernel/crypto/async_tx/async_memcpy.ko
kernel/crypto/async_tx/async_pq.ko
kernel/crypto/async_tx/async_raid6_recov.ko
kernel/crypto/async_tx/async_tx.ko
kernel/crypto/async_tx/async_xor.ko
kernel/crypto/authenc.ko
kernel/crypto/cbc.ko
kernel/crypto/cmac.ko
kernel/crypto/crc32c_generic.ko
kernel/crypto/crct10dif_common.ko
kernel/crypto/crct10dif_generic.ko
kernel/crypto/cryptd.ko
kernel/crypto/crypto_simd.ko
kernel/crypto/drbg.ko
kernel/crypto/ecc.ko
kernel/crypto/ecdh_generic.ko
kernel/crypto/essiv.ko
kernel/crypto/xor.ko
kernel/crypto/xts.ko
kernel/drivers/crypto
kernel/drivers/crypto/ccp
kernel/drivers/crypto/ccp/ccp.ko
kernel/drivers/crypto/padlock-aes.ko
kernel/lib/crypto
kernel/lib/crypto/libaes.ko
x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1
x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

I'm not sure what's changed; if somebody could help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". If you have a solution, then consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer If you don't think it's worthwhile adding a solution, then consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using trial and error and comparing kernel modules with an ArchLinux system I found that adding ecb and ccm modules to the initrd allowed the system to boot.